# Overwrite checked radio button and check other one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have two radio buttons. One is checked by default but I want to uncheck that one and check an other one by default.

So I have this HTML:

```
<div class="gui-radio">
  <input type="radio" value="register" name="choise" id="new-register">
  <label for="register">Register</label>
</div>
<div class="gui-radio">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="guest" name="choise" id="new-guest">
  <label for="new-guest">Guest</label>
 </div>
```

This all automatically generated. I need this to be done with Jquery.

So How do I uncheck the second one and check the first one?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with jQuery when its provided out of the box as native functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery 1.6+**

You can check a checkbox by setting `.prop('checked', true);` and uncheck it by setting `.prop('checked', false);`.

```
$('#new-register').prop('checked', true);
$('#new-guest').prop('checked', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$('#new-register').attr('checked','checked');
$('#new-guest').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: It would be better to use `$('#new-register').prop('checked', true);` and `$('#new-guest').prop('checked', false);` as Checked is a property

Answer (score 1):

They are already connected by their `name` attributes, so all you need to do is make the first one checked - the second one will automatically become unchecked, because in a radio group only one can be selected.

This is how you make a radio/checkbox checked in jQuery:

```
$('#new-register').prop('checked', true);
```

- [Remember to use `prop`, not `attr`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AALRF/)

Answer (score 1):

This checks the first radio:

```
jQuery('input#new-register').prop('checked', true);
```

Also closing the inputs might be a good idea:

```
<div class="gui-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="register" name="choise" id="new-register" />
    <label for="register">Register</label>
</div>
<div class="gui-radio">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="guest" name="choise" id="new-guest" />
    <label for="new-guest">Guest</label>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/46gg6/)